# Remove label from filled DesktopDatePicker Material UI

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui, frontend

I want to remove the label from the `DesktopDatePicker` in Material UI. I removed the label prop, and achieved that, but now the placeholder text is shifted lower. For some reason, this doesn't happen with the default (outlined) variant.

I want to use the filled variant and achieve the same composition.

Here's what it looks like after removing the label:

[image]

And with the outlined variant it looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
              <DesktopDatePicker
                inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                value={null}
                onChange={(newValue: Dayjs | null) => console.log(newValue)}
                InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    variant="filled"
                    sx={{
                      ".MuiInputBase-root": {
                        borderRadius: "10px",
                      },
                    }}
                    {...params}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the styles so that you override the default filled input styles.

Update your SX prop to the below (have used the padding values from the outlined input).

```
 sx={{
     ".MuiInputBase-root": {
         borderRadius: "10px",
      },
      ".MuiFilledInput-input": {
         padding: "16.5px 14px",
      }
 }}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Solved it for me. The .MuiFilledInput-input override did the trick.